# How to log out using jwt token in node backend

Tags: jwt, backend, logout

I have used jwt token to login

```
const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
```

.

Below is my  code for router

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        // validate
        if (!email || !password)
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Not all fields have been entered." });

        const user = await Customer.findOne({ email: email });
        if (!user)
            return res
                .status(400)
                .json({ msg: "No account with this email has been registered." });

        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Invalid credentials." });

        const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        res.json({
            token,
            user: {
                id: user._id,
                displayName: user.displayName,
            },
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
});
```

Can anybody provide code for loging out using jwt token

Comment: Please close this question. If the answer is solved your question. Otherwise, please respond with comments

Answer (score 0):

You just need to invalidate your jwt token in logout

more than one way you can achieve. Here I am going to explain a couple of ways

1.storing token in an array. In log out, you can remove the token

```
const refreshTokens = []; --> global declaration
```

in login, before `res.json({...});`

```
refreshTokens.push(refreshToken);
```

the constraint here is jwt tokens are time-bounded. You need to get a refresh token if old token expires. Whenever you issue a refresh token you need to remove the old and push the latest

```
router.post('/refreshtoken', function (req, res) { 

  const { token } = req.body;

if (!token) {
    return res.sendStatus(401);
}

if (!refreshTokens.includes(token)) {
    return res.sendStatus(403);
}

jwt.verify(token, refreshTokenSecret, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.sendStatus(403);
    }

    const accessToken = jwt.sign({ username: user.username, role: user.role }, accessTokenSecret, { expiresIn: '20m' });
    refreshTokens = refreshTokens.filter(token => t !== token);
    refreshTokens.push(accessToken);

    res.json({
        accessToken
     });
  });
 });
```

In Logout you need to invalidate token

```
 app.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
    const { token } = req.body;
    refreshTokens = refreshTokens.filter(token => t !== token);

    res.send("Logout successful");
 });
```

2.Store token in cookie whenever you log in or reissues the token. verify jwt token from cookie instead of reading from headers.

```
res.cookie('jwt_token', token, {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + expiration),
    secure: false, // set to true if your using https
    httpOnly: true,
  });
```

In Logout destroy the cookie

```
router.get('/logout', function (req, res) { 
  res.clearCookie('jwt_token');
  req.session.destroy(); 
});
```